# How to convert equations from matrix to tensor (indicial) notation: methods and tips?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble with converting equations from matrix to tensor notation and vice versa. For example, from literature I see that the matrix equation
$$\bf{a} = \bf{A^TBx} \tag{1}$$
can be written in tensor notation as
$$a_i=A_{ki}B_{kj}x_j \tag{2}$$

If I was faced with an equation such as Eqn(1) and wanted to write it in tensor notation I wouldn't know how to begin. At best I would write:
$$a_i=A_{ji} B_{ij} x_i \tag{3}$$
since I have just learned to write vectors and tensors as $x_i$ and $X_{ij}$, respectively, and I know that the transpose of a tensor is $(\bf{A^T})_{ij}$$=A_{ji}$.

Obviously Eqn(3) is meaningless because the rules of index notation dictate that the same index (subscript) may not appear more than twice in a product of two (or more) vectors or tensors. And this is where I run into trouble, I have difficulty in understanding how I correctly change the pairs of i’s and j’s to k’s, l’s, m’s, etc. **Is there some formulaic way to go about this? When you are faced with this step, how do you think and go about the manipulation? I have the same questions for when one wants to write an equation written in tensor notation to matrix notation.**